# How to debug into a nuget-fetched package?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I've been away from .Net development for a few years, and predictably... everything has changed.   So I have a sample app which depends on an upstream nuget project (RestSharp).  The sample app doesn't work, and I want to debug into some of the RestSharp calls to get a better understanding of how that works.     But the RestSharp code as dragged in by nuget is just DLLs, no symbols or source code... and my attempts to build RestSharp on its own are stumbling over my unfamiliarity with newer .Net and Visual Studio mechanisms.

How can I debug into the RestSharp code -- either by getting the symbols and source pushed to the right local spots, or by building RestSharp from source?

#### Edit

The RestSharp build failure message:

```
C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\.nuget\nuget.targets(58,9): error : Access is denied.
1>C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\.nuget\nuget.targets(58,9): error MSB3075: The command    
    ""C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\.nuget\nuget.exe" install ^
    "C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\RestSharp\packages.config" -source ""^
    -o "C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\packages""
exited with code 5.
Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command
```

#### Re-edit

It turns out that this error meant exactly what it said (who'da thunk?):  the process of fetching the source code for RestSharp delivered a nuget.exe without exec permission.  That's fixed, and now RestSharp builds.

But the question still stands—what conventions/resources/common practices surround this problem of debugging 3rd party nuget libraries?  Does everybody fetch the original source and build it in isolation of the nuget infrastructure?

Comment: Are you using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)? It's a popular tool nowadays for .NET development, and it allows you to decompile DLLs into source that you can step into. As for building [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) itself, what problems are you having? Can you describe them? Also, what sample app are you trying to debug?

Comment: I'm not using ReSharper.  I have heard of it, at least -- I don't think it existed the last time I did lots of .Net (neither did nuget.  I think I was on Vs2003 or something at the time!).   I'd prefer to debug with the real source and symbols, although that's an interesting note-for-later.  The main problem is that RestSharp's build is failing with an access denied on some operation involving nuget.exe.   I have to fetch that back from source control to give more details.   Will do that soon.

Comment: C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\.nuget\nuget.targets(58,9): error : Access is denied.
1>C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\.nuget\nuget.targets(58,9): error MSB3075: The command ""C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\RestSharp\packages.config" -source "" -o "C:\cpotech\3rdparty\RestSharp\packages"" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.

Comment: So I haven't tried to track down permissions issues on this yet, my first groan was "dang, you can't build the source without some dependency on nuget?".   So I started trying to break out that dependency, as it seemed probably unnecessary to RestSharp core logic.  Then I found that RestSharp depends on SimpleJson, and that took away my enthusiasm for breaking the dependency tool. :)

Comment: If the authors choose to they can publish symbol packages to http://www.symbolsource.org/ and then you can download them during `nuget install` with the `-source` switch. Unfortunately it looks like RestSharp is not there.

Comment: Ok, well that's good to know.  I figured there must be conventions for handling this problem, but it's one of those things that's hard to google because it's a bit abstract -- i.e. "what's the common practice for debugging into 3rd party packages with nuget" returns nothing relevant.

Comment: @Cupcake: I omitted the details about the sample app, because it's not publicly available and not really the problem of interest to me... I want to understand the general practices for how to debug these 3rd party libs, solving the immediate bug is only of limited value compared to that larger question.

Comment: @Stabledog when you get a chance, you should edit your question to add the error information, instead of leaving them in the comments (easier for people to find and read). I'll see if I can reproduce your errors later.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that -- but now that error is solved.  It looks like a rare case of Windows reporting a useful error condition that isn't just masking some massive failure of underlying subsystems! -- i.e. the nuget.exe referenced in the error didn't have exec permission.  I suppose it probably came down in my fetch of the public source repository, and that process failed to mark it executable by yours truly.    So now RestSharp builds, and I will see if I can get the debugger to drill down.   Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to make a note to learn more about Resharper and symbolsource.org, so thanks for those tips, gentlemen.